# Go: Passing functions through channels

Tags: go, concurrency, rate-limiting

I'm trying to rate limit the functions that I call by placing them through a queue to be accessed later. Below I have a slice of requests that I have created, and the requestHandler function processes each request at a certain rate.

I want it to accept all kinds of functions with different types of parameters, hence the interface{} type.

How would I be able to pass the functions through a channel and successfully call them?

```
type request struct {
    function interface{}
    channel  chan interface{}
}

var requestQueue []request

func pushQueue(f interface{}, ch chan interface{}) {
    req := request{
        f,
        ch,
    }

    //push
    requestQueue = append(requestQueue, req)
}

func requestHandler() {
    for {
        if len(requestQueue) > 0 {
            //pop
            req := requestQueue[len(requestQueue)-1]
            requestQueue = requestQueue[:len(requestQueue)-1]

            req.channel <- req.function
        }

        <-time.After(1200 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve (GetLeagueEntries(string, string) and GetSummonerName(int, int) are functions):

```
ch := make(chan interface{})
    pushQueue(l.GetLeagueEntries, ch)
    pushQueue(l.GetSummonerName, ch)

    leagues, _ := <-ch(string1, string2)
    summoners, _ := <-ch(int1, int2)
```

Comment: why do you want to limit rate of the function calls? rate limiting access to the actual limited resource (such as netwrok, disk, etc) might be easier to implement. Also have a look at https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate

Comment: Because these function calls are external library calls that are tied to an API. I have to limit my own functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, here is the codez: https://play.golang.org/p/XZvb_4BaJF

*Notice that it's not perfect. You have a queue that is executed every second. If the queue is empty and a new item is added, the new item can wait for almost a second before being executed.*

But this should get you very close to what you need anyway :)

This code can be split into 3 section:

1. The rate limited queue executor, which I call the server (I'm horrible at naming things) - The server doesn't know anything about the functions. All it does is start a never-ending goroutine that pops the oldest function in the queue, once every second, and calls it. The issue that I talked about above is in this section of the code BTW and I could help you fix it if you want.
2. The Button Click functionality - This shows you how each button click could call 3 diff functions (you could obviously make more/less function calls) using the server and make sure that they are each 1 second apart from each other. You can even add a timeout to any of the functions (to fake latency) and they would still get called 1 second apart. This is the only place that you need channels because you want to make all the function calls as fast as possible (if the first function takes 5 seconds, you only want to wait 1 second to call the second function) and then wait for them to finish so you need to know when they are all done.
3. The Button Click simulation (the main func) - this just shows that 3 button clicks would work as expected. You can also put them in a goroutine to simulate 3 users clicking the button at the same time and it would still work.

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "fmt"
       "sync"
       "time"
   )

   const (
       requestFreq = time.Second
   )

   type (
       // A single request
       request func()

       // The server that will hold a queue of requests and make them once a requestFreq
       server struct {
           // This will tick once per requestFreq
           ticker     *time.Ticker

           requests []request
           // Mutex for working with the request slice
           sync.RWMutex
       }
   )

   var (
       createServerOnce sync.Once
       s *server
   )

   func main() {
       // Multiple button clicks:
       ButtonClick()
       ButtonClick()
       ButtonClick()

       fmt.Println("Done!")
   }






   // BUTTON LOGIC:

   // Calls 3 functions and returns 3 diff values.
   // Each function is called at least 1 second appart.
   func ButtonClick() (val1 int, val2 string, val3 bool) {
       iCh := make(chan int)
       sCh := make(chan string)
       bCh := make(chan bool)

       go func(){
           Server().AppendRequest(func() {
               t := time.Now()
               fmt.Println("Calling func1 (time: " + t.Format("15:04:05") + ")")
               // do some stuff
               iCh <- 1
           })
       }()
       go func(){
           Server().AppendRequest(func() {
               t := time.Now()
               fmt.Println("Calling func2 (time: " + t.Format("15:04:05") + ")")
               // do some stuff
               sCh <- "Yo"
           })
       }()
       go func(){
           Server().AppendRequest(func() {
               t := time.Now()
               fmt.Println("Calling func3 (time: " + t.Format("15:04:05") + ")")
               // do some stuff
               bCh <- true
           })
       }()

       // Wait for all 3 calls to come back
       for count := 0; count < 3; count++ {
           select {
           case val1 = <-iCh:
           case val2 = <-sCh:
           case val3 = <-bCh:
           }
       }

       return
   }





   // SERVER LOGIC

   // Factory function that will only create a single server
   func Server() *server {
       // Only one server for the entire application
       createServerOnce.Do(func() {
           s = &server{ticker: time.NewTicker(requestFreq), requests: []request{}}

           // Start a thread to make requests.
           go s.makeRequests()
       })
       return s
   }
   func (s *server) makeRequests() {
       if s == nil || s.ticker == nil {
           return
       }

       // This will keep going once per each requestFreq
       for _ = range s.ticker.C {

           var r request

           // You can't just access s.requests because you are in a goroutine
           // here while someone could be adding new requests outside of the 
           // goroutine so you have to use locks.
           s.Lock()
           if len(s.requests) > 0 {
               // We have a lock here, which blocks all other operations 
               // so just shift the first request out, save it and give 
               // the lock back before doing any work.
               r = s.requests[0]
               s.requests = s.requests[1:]
           }
           s.Unlock()

           if r != nil {
               // make the request!
               r()
           }
       }
   }
   func (s *server) AppendRequest(r request) {
       if s == nil {
           return
       }
       s.Lock()
       s.requests = append(s.requests, r)
       s.Unlock()
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

First, I would write it as:

```
leagues := server.GetLeagueEntries()
summoners := server.GetSummoners()
```

And, put the rate limiting into the server. With one of the rate-limiting libraries.

However, it is possible to use an interface to unify the requests, and use a func type to allow closures (as in http.HandleFunc):

```
type Command interface {
    Execute(server *Server)
}

type CommandFunc func(server *Server)
func (fn CommandFunc) Execute(server *Server) { fn(server) }

type GetLeagueEntries struct { Leagues []League }

func (entries *GetLeagueEntries) Execute(server *Server) {
    // ...
}

func GetSummonerName(id int, result *string) CommandFunc {
    return CommandFunc(func(server *Server){
        *result = "hello"
    })
}

get := GetLeagueEnties{}
requests <- &get

requests <- CommandFunc(func(server *Server){
    // ... handle struff here
})
```

Of course, this needs some synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought it easier to use some sort of semaphore or worker pool. That way you have limited number of workers who can do anything. It would be possible to have multiple worker pools too.

Do you need any of these calls to be concurrent/asynchronous? If not, and they can be called in order you could have configurable sleep (a nasty hack mind).

Try out a worker pool or semaphore rather than a chan of functions.

Comment: The main problem is finding a way to rate limit my api calls but I'm finding trouble figuring out a way to delay these concurrent calls.